# Bug with google play services when SavedGames enabled Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm trying to do a gogle play cloud save but when I enable the saved games option in the code, authentication stops working. What could be the problem?
If i write this connection will not be((
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false).EnableSavedGames().Build();
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);

```
adb logcat 
1C4
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** DEVELOPER_ERROR
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): **     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): **     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): **     a test account.
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): ** (4) A server auth code was requested, but an incorrect client
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): **     id was provided. The client id for server auth codes should
E/PlayGamesServices[SignInAuthenticator](32263): **     be the client id for the game server (not the android app).
```

if i write this code and comment

```
   //PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false).EnableSavedGames().Build();
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
            //PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
            PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
            Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
               if(success)
                {
                    OpenSave(false);
                }
               else
                {
                    
                }
            });
```

everything works, but saving to the cloud doesn't work, please can you help?) How I can fix this trouble?)

Comment: Wouldn't the first line of your question be a far more descriptive question title than the nebulous "Bug with Google Play Services when SavedGames enabled Unity"?

Comment: ok, next time I'll keep that in mind